# How 'similar' should names be to qualify as possible duplicates?

Tags: forms, validation

This is with reference to [this question about possible duplicates](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/68291/when-should-i-prompt-the-user-for-duplicates-entries).

The question now arises is, how similar should these names be to mark them as possible duplicates?

For example,
Rajan Electricals and Rjaan/Rajn/Rjan Electricals are a close match.
But, Should we also prompt for something like Rajan Electronics? Would it be wise to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: I would think it depends on the application. If you are classifying electronics suppliers then you would differentiate between 'electricals' and 'electronics'. If you are referring to businesses or surnames then these two might be grouped. Google has legions of ppl who do nothing more than associate similar phrases like this.

Comment: What does the client want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what we are going to do.

We are going to 'warn' the user about the similarity criteria in the following cases:

1. There's a spelling mistake in *any* of the constituent words of the name and there exists a name already. Eg. Rajan Electricals and Rjaan Electricals.
2. There's a word which has a short abbreviation in use, and the rest of the words match exactly or like point 1. Eg, Shailesh Tubes Private Limited and Shailesh Tubes Pvt. Ltd. should match.